# Meteor {{#if currentUser}} not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, router, iron-router

I have a block of code wrapped in a meteor {{#if currentUser}} block as so:

```html
<template name="setup">
  {{#if currentUser}} {{> step1}} {{else}} {{redirect}} {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="setup2">
  {{#if currentUser}} {{> step2}} {{else}} {{redirect}} {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="step1">
  <div class="fullscreen">
    Setup: Step 1 of 2
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{pathFor 'setup2'}}">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template name="step2">
  <div class="fullscreen">
    Setup: Step 2 of 2
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{pathFor 'setup'}}">Previous</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">Complete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and a helper function redirect in my javascript like this:

```js
      //setup redirects
     Template.setup.helpers({
       redirect: function() {
         return Router.go('login');
       }
     });
     Template.setup2.helpers({
       redirect: function() {
         return Router.go('login');
       }
     });
```

However, when I visit the /setup or /setup2 pages they always redirect to the login page, even if a current user is logged in. What could be causing this? Appreciate any help. Thank You!

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing you should not be doing with helpers - see the "Overworked helpers" section of [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes). The correct way to deal with this is in the router.

Answer (score 3):

Like David Weldon says you can use iron:router for this. to be more specific an `Router.onBeforeAction` for example.

Create te function and the hook like this.

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      this.render('redirect');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'setup'});
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'setup2'});
```

Or on the `data:function(){}`, like this.

```
data:function(){
  if(!Meteor.userId()){
    this.render('redirect')
   }else{
    this.next();
   }
}
```

So with this, you can delete the template helpers and do this on the router logic.

Answer (score 2):

`currentUser` is null because user is logging in. So check `{{ loggingIn }}` before check current user. It'll may work but it is not what helpers supposed to do.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_loggingin